# How can I get rid of a large hornet nest in my hollow tree?

Tags: pest-control, insects

I have an old hollow black cherry tree and sandhills hornets moved in this year. The hole is about one foot from the ground. How can I get rid of the nest without a professional?

Comment: @jmusser Some what related: [How can I discourage wasps?](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/1517/394)

Comment: @jmusser A quick search on the web shows "sandhills hornets" to a be form of "yellow jackets" therefore I can't recommend strongly enough not to tackle them yourself. "Yellow jackets" are aggressive, dangerous wasps that will attack you in large numbers if they feel threatened & they are capable of stinging multiple times, each sting is (very) painful.

Comment: They are about 2-1/2" long. That'd be about the biggest yellow jacket I've ever seen. Do you think I could attack them before they warm up enough to fly?   It has been pretty cold around here.

Comment: @jmusser 2½inches (62.5mm) is huge! Are you positive they are "sandhills hornets"? If you really want to tackle it yourself (again, I strongly recommend you don't), take a look here: [Yellowjacket Nest? "Clean it Up" Without Turning to Terrible Toxins](http://www.gardensalive.com/article.asp?ai=949)

Comment: At the very least, make sure the house is closed up and children and pets are safely inside. If you've got neighbors nearby it would be good to give them a heads-up as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're not averse to using insecticides, then you'll find several in any of the home repair big-box stores, that specifically target hornets and wasps. Just make sure you cover yourself well from head to toe, eye protection, etc. the full deal (with as many layers as you can... you really don't want to get stung).

Most of these sprays work from afar (about 5-10 feet away), so you won't have to get too close to the nest. However, do remember to spray it only at night time, as that's when the hornets are mostly inactive (a.k.a taking a few winks).

Lastly and most importantly, **don't forget to read the directions on the can**!

Answer (score 3):

Don't try it yourself. Although you can flood the nest and kill most of the hornets, there should be some other hornet flying outside, which can attack you right away.

Don't hesitate to contact your local bureau for environmental protection or pest control group. Just a phone call to them, and they should eliminate the hornet for free ( That's their job! ) . When they arrive, remember to keep your windows closed.